# IdentityServer4 Admin API always return 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

I have IdentityServer4 running at https://localhost:44311/. I am building a custom User Interface using IdentityServer4 Admin APIs. I wrote a small program to test if I could correctly call Admin API from C# code. This sample program gets the Bearer token correctly but when I call GET Tenant Admin API, it always returns the status code 403 Forbidden.

On more technical side, when I run Program.cs, I receive a Bearer token. I set this token using client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken); but when I send GET request to Admin API using await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44302/api/Tenant");, I receive 403 Forbidden. What am I missing? Here is code:

**Program.cs**

```
using IdentityModel.Client;
using System.Text;

await SampleAdminApi();
async Task SampleAdminApi()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "https://localhost:44311/connect/token",
        ClientId = "skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui",
        ClientSecret = "1Browndog32",
        Scope = "skoruba_identity_admin_api"
    });

    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get token", tokenResponse.Exception);
    }

    client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

    var response1 = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44302/api/Tenant");
    var content1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Edited - API side Program.cs and Startup.cs**

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Shared.Configuration.Helpers;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = GetConfiguration(args);

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                DockerHelpers.ApplyDockerConfiguration(configuration);

                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        private static IConfiguration GetConfiguration(string[] args)
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var isDevelopment = environment == Environments.Development;

            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile("serilog.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"serilog.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            if (isDevelopment)
            {
                configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>(true);
            }

            var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            configuration.AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(configurationBuilder);

            configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
            configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            return configurationBuilder.Build();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                 {
                     var configurationRoot = configApp.Build();

                     configApp.AddJsonFile("serilog.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                     var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;

                     configApp.AddJsonFile($"serilog.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                     if (env.IsDevelopment())
                     {
                         configApp.AddUserSecrets<Startup>(true);
                     }

                     configurationRoot.AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(configApp);

                     configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                     configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                 })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false);
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfig) =>
                {
                    loggerConfig
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostContext.Configuration)
                        .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", hostContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName);
                });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Skoruba.AuditLogging.EntityFramework.Entities;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Configuration;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Configuration.Authorization;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.ExceptionHandling;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Helpers;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Mappers;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Resources;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.EntityFramework.Interfaces;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.EntityFramework.Shared.DbContexts;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.EntityFramework.Shared.Entities.Identity;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Shared.Configuration.Helpers;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Shared.Dtos;
using Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Shared.Dtos.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            HostingEnvironment = env;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var adminApiConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AdminApiConfiguration)).Get<AdminApiConfiguration>();
            services.AddSingleton(adminApiConfiguration);

            // Add DbContexts
            RegisterDbContexts(services);

            services.AddDataProtection<IdentityServerDataProtectionDbContext>(Configuration);

            // Add email senders which is currently setup for SendGrid and SMTP
            services.AddEmailSenders(Configuration);

            services.AddScoped<ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute>();
            services.AddScoped<IApiErrorResources, ApiErrorResources>();

            // Add authentication services
            RegisterAuthentication(services);

            // Add authorization services
            RegisterAuthorization(services);

            var profileTypes = new HashSet<Type>
            {
                typeof(IdentityMapperProfile<IdentityRoleDto, IdentityUserRolesDto, string, IdentityUserClaimsDto, IdentityUserClaimDto, IdentityUserProviderDto, IdentityUserProvidersDto, IdentityUserChangePasswordDto, IdentityRoleClaimDto, IdentityRoleClaimsDto>)
            };

            services.AddAdminAspNetIdentityServices<AdminIdentityDbContext, IdentityServerPersistedGrantDbContext,
                IdentityUserDto, IdentityRoleDto, UserIdentity, UserIdentityRole, string, UserIdentityUserClaim, UserIdentityUserRole,
                UserIdentityUserLogin, UserIdentityRoleClaim, UserIdentityUserToken,
                IdentityUsersDto, IdentityRolesDto, IdentityUserRolesDto,
                IdentityUserClaimsDto, IdentityUserProviderDto, IdentityUserProvidersDto, IdentityUserChangePasswordDto,
                IdentityRoleClaimsDto, IdentityUserClaimDto, IdentityRoleClaimDto>(profileTypes);

            services.AddAdminServices<IdentityServerConfigurationDbContext, IdentityServerPersistedGrantDbContext, AdminLogDbContext, AdminTenantManagementSystemDbContext>();

            services.AddAdminApiCors(adminApiConfiguration);

            services.AddMvcServices<IdentityUserDto, IdentityRoleDto,
                UserIdentity, UserIdentityRole, string, UserIdentityUserClaim, UserIdentityUserRole,
                UserIdentityUserLogin, UserIdentityRoleClaim, UserIdentityUserToken,
                IdentityUsersDto, IdentityRolesDto, IdentityUserRolesDto,
                IdentityUserClaimsDto, IdentityUserProviderDto, IdentityUserProvidersDto, IdentityUserChangePasswordDto,
                IdentityRoleClaimsDto, IdentityUserClaimDto, IdentityRoleClaimDto>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc(adminApiConfiguration.ApiVersion, new OpenApiInfo { Title = adminApiConfiguration.ApiName, Version = adminApiConfiguration.ApiVersion });

                options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{adminApiConfiguration.IdentityServerBaseUrl}/connect/authorize"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri($"{adminApiConfiguration.IdentityServerBaseUrl}/connect/token"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                { adminApiConfiguration.OidcApiName, adminApiConfiguration.ApiName }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
            });

            services.AddAuditEventLogging<AdminAuditLogDbContext, AuditLog>(Configuration);

            services.AddIdSHealthChecks<IdentityServerConfigurationDbContext, IdentityServerPersistedGrantDbContext, AdminIdentityDbContext, AdminLogDbContext, AdminAuditLogDbContext, IdentityServerDataProtectionDbContext>(Configuration, adminApiConfiguration);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AdminApiConfiguration adminApiConfiguration)
        {
            app.AddForwardHeaders();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{adminApiConfiguration.ApiBaseUrl}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", adminApiConfiguration.ApiName);

                c.OAuthClientId(adminApiConfiguration.OidcSwaggerUIClientId);
                c.OAuthAppName(adminApiConfiguration.ApiName);
                c.OAuthUsePkce();
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            UseAuthentication(app);
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
                {
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
            });
        }

        public virtual void RegisterDbContexts(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContexts<AdminIdentityDbContext, IdentityServerConfigurationDbContext, IdentityServerPersistedGrantDbContext, AdminLogDbContext, AdminAuditLogDbContext, IdentityServerDataProtectionDbContext, AuditLog, AdminTenantManagementSystemDbContext>(Configuration);
        }

        public virtual void RegisterAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApiAuthentication<AdminIdentityDbContext, UserIdentity, UserIdentityRole>(Configuration);
        }

        public virtual void RegisterAuthorization(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthorizationPolicies();
        }

        public virtual void UseAuthentication(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

**TenantController.cs**

```
namespace Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [TypeFilter(typeof(ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute))]
    [Produces("application/json", "application/problem+json")]
    [Authorize(Policy = AuthorizationConsts.UserPolicy)]
    public class TenantController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITenantService _tenantService;
         
        public TenantController(ITenantService tenantService)
        {
            _tenantService = tenantService;
             
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IList<BusinessLogic.Dtos.Tenants.TenantDto>>> Get()
        {
            var environment= HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "EnvironmentId").FirstOrDefault();
            var tenantDto = await _tenantService.GetByEnvironmentIdAsync(Guid.Parse(environment.Value));

            return Ok(tenantDto);
        }
    }
}
```

**Token**

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkJEQTFFRURDNjNDQkVDNDY4N0Q5MzdDNThCM0ZBQjYxIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2NzQ0NTgwMTYsImV4cCI6MTY3NDQ2MTYxNiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTEiLCJhdWQiOiJza29ydWJhX2lkZW50aXR5X2FkbWluX2FwaSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InNrb3J1YmFfaWRlbnRpdHlfYWRtaW5fYXBpX3N3YWdnZXJ1aSIsImp0aSI6IkY4RUU3Q0Y5Q0VDQ0VGNUE5QUYxRTYzOUY0QzMzNjZDIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc0NDU4MDE2LCJzY29wZSI6WyJza29ydWJhX2lkZW50aXR5X2FkbWluX2FwaSJdfQ.agFbtWl3Mzwwx0vdB7ZBKXVStRSAlmQ7LMKQoJNPyKxYoKQE0y4IvH-gGNXPwW2C_VqSc22nXq_Vj_iVkyJZJeZjL6JARBvaqABRJNuWjqc5dP95ilhcNLiMcac8MLdXwkbNi9SFGXjBTZgG6927f_zvz8GSQCAbC1M7NoNbCId6DVkJ2jTikym-XvF91L6Azh6zavJHrJ-Wp9SPWuWve8R8wZHuS8ipPvzEEctn2_L7NVwYVkjmF8nFh5Ok2BqEZ_isyF7JtG1-2rOt8WXh8qXScyRWriRszhK3kR-qmpnuITuUdvH8qQf5ts63PfRjZfpx3KSE1XR1M-S4qP79iA","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"skoruba_identity_admin_api"}
```

**jwt.ms - failed to call api with this toeken obtained in C# code using HttpClient**

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "BDA1EEDC63CBEC4687D937C58B3FAB61",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}.{
  "nbf": 1674458016,
  "exp": 1674461616,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44311",
  "aud": "skoruba_identity_admin_api",
  "client_id": "skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui",
  "jti": "F8EE7CF9CECCEF5A9AF1E639F4C3366C",
  "iat": 1674458016,
  "scope": [
    "skoruba_identity_admin_api"
  ]
}.[Signature]
```

**jwt.ms - success to call api with this token, obtained from swagger ui**

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "BDA1EEDC63CBEC4687D937C58B3FAB61",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}.{
  "nbf": 1674459182,
  "exp": 1674462782,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44311",
  "aud": "skoruba_identity_admin_api",
  "client_id": "skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui",
  "sub": "f8313f8a-e697-4303-8976-81b3580e6988",
  "auth_time": 1674119404,
  "idp": "local",
  "EnvironmentId": "6c70390a-53c9-4def-ed22-08da5acc7c00",
  "role": "SkorubaIdentityAdminAdministrator",
  "name": "rafey",
  "jti": "46DA46DA3B9E552D934A3E2FFE55A7BF",
  "sid": "877C321BA10FC696149C57754D9C5D95",
  "iat": 1674459182,
  "scope": [
    "skoruba_identity_admin_api"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: can you add the code that configures your api to the question ( program.cs/startup.cs)

Comment: The 403 error means you don't have the enough permission to access the admin api itself. Could you please check you have set the role for the admin api or the token you have generated contains the enough role information inside it?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I have added api side program.cs/startup.cs in question

Comment: @BrandoZhang, I have added token in question as well as API controller that I am trying to call from C# code.

Comment: how is UserPolicy defined? (your authorization policy?)

Comment: @ToreNestenius,  `[Authorize(Policy = AuthorizationConsts.UserPolicy)]` is defined as `public const string UserPolicy = "RequireUserRole";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you might need to tell The authentication handler, what the name of your role claim is. by default, Microsoft and OpenID Connect have different opinion on what the name of the claim should be.

So, typically, you set it using this code construct inside AddJwtBearer().

```
   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
      NameClaimType = "email"
      RoleClaimType = "role"
   };
```

However, I am unsure how to do it in your particular code.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Hope this can give you clues.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)
and [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: could you also answer this question: ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75231113/identityserver4-auth-error-typeerror-failed-to-fetch )